# How can i do this in css/html?

Tags: html, css

How can i make this boxes with css? Analyzing the code of the page I noticed that there is a div which in turn is formed by two other divs, that of the image and that of the text

example 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFSGX.png

 example 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXISy.png

Comment: what box? And show the code from your attempts.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Sorry, now i added 2 image of the boxes. I have made no attempt because I do not know how to start

Comment: Here at SO you need to make an effort of your own first, with the markup you intend to use

Comment: @HardaChadi here's a starting point https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/bWXvVX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.outer{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.outer > .inner{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute; 
  padding: 10px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index:1; 
}
```

```html
<div class="outer" style="background:url(http://lorempixel.com/600/300/)center center no-repeat;background-size:cover">&nbsp;<div class="inner">Some text here</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you would like to do is overlay a transparent div over an image. I have written the html and css for this and created a plunk for you here: http://embed.plnkr.co/7Qeh2C/. The code is also below:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello Hardar!</h1>
<div class="container">
<img style="width:400px" src="http://www.davemphotographics.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/CSP-Headshots-533-Edit.jpg"></img>
<div class="overlay"><p>Test</p></div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
position:relative;
width: 400px;
}

.overlay {
position: absolute;
height:60px;
bottom: 0;
width:400px;
background-color:#444;
opacity: .8;
}

.overlay p {
color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. If it worked for you could you approve my answer (click up arrow)